# Increasing progress bar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to increase or decrease the width of an element as a progress bar using jQuery and JavaScript. I'm new to JavaScript and something is missing in my code to work.

Can anyone help me this to work? Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var 
    width1 = $("#bar-one").width(),   
    width2 = $("#bar-two").width();
    
 $("#one").on("click", function(){
    $('#bar-one').css('width', width1 + '5%'),
    $('#bar-two').css('width', width2 - '5%');
 } else {
   $('#bar-one').css('width', width1 - '5%'),
    $('#bar-two').css('width', width2 + '5%');
  });
  
  $("#two").on("click", function(){
    $('#bar-one').css('width', width1 + '10%'),
    $('#bar-two').css('width', width2 - '5%');
 } else {
   $('#bar-one').css('width', width1 - '10%'),
    $('#bar-two').css('width', width2 + '5%');
  });
  
  $("#three").on("click", function(){
    $('#bar-one').css('width', width1 + '05%'),
    $('#bar-two').css('width', width2 - '15%');
 } else {
   $('#bar-one').css('width', width1 - '5%'),
    $('#bar-two').css('width', width2 + '15%');
  });
})
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: silver;
}

#bar-one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
}

#bar-two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="bar-one" style="width:30%"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="bar-two" style="width:45%"></div>
</div>
<br>
<input id="one" type="checkbox">
<input id="two" type="checkbox">
<input id="three" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: I see three `else` statements with no `if` conditions. What is your exact requirement ?

Comment: For example: When a checkbox is checked, then the value increases, if is checked again (to disable it) the value must come back where it was. It must be a syntax error by me, sorry

Comment: In JavaScript, `number + string` will coerce the `number` to String, then concatenate `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

you get the error because of `else` without `if` condition

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var width1 = $("#bar-one")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');  
  var width2 = $("#bar-two")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');

 $("#one").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
 var width1 = $("#bar-one")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');  
  var width2 = $("#bar-two")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');
  $('#bar-one').width((parseInt(width1)+5)+"%");
  $('#bar-two').width((parseInt(width2)-5)+"%");
  } else {
 var width1 = $("#bar-one")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');  
  var width2 = $("#bar-two")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');
  $('#bar-one').width((parseInt(width1)-5)+"%");
  $('#bar-two').width((parseInt(width2)+5)+"%");
  }
 });
  
  $("#two").on("click", function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     var width1 = $("#bar-one")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');  
  var width2 = $("#bar-two")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');
    $('#bar-one').width((parseInt(width1) + 10)+"%");
    $('#bar-two').width((parseInt(width2)-5)+"%");
 } else {
   var width1 = $("#bar-one")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');  
  var width2 = $("#bar-two")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');
   $('#bar-one').width((parseInt(width1) - 10)+"%");
    $('#bar-two').width((parseInt(width2)+5)+"%");
}
  });
  
  $("#three").on("click", function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     var width1 = $("#bar-one")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');  
  var width2 = $("#bar-two")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');
    $('#bar-one').width((parseInt(width1)+5)+"%");
    $('#bar-two').width((parseInt(width2) - 15)+"%");
 } else {
   var width1 = $("#bar-one")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');  
  var width2 = $("#bar-two")[0].style.width.replace('%', '');
   $('#bar-one').width((parseInt(width1)-5)+"%");
    $('#bar-two').width((parseInt(width2) + 15)+"%");
}
  });
  
});
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: silver;
}

#bar-one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  transition: width .6s linear
}

#bar-two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  transition: width .6s linear
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="bar-one" style="width:30%"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="bar-two" style="width:45%"></div>
</div>
<br>
<input id="one" type="checkbox">
<input id="two" type="checkbox">
<input id="three" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: glad to help you:)